# Java Garbage Collection log output

Tags: java, logging, garbage-collection, jvm

Good Morning,

I am writing a program that parses Java Garbage collection and I need some help in determining what exactly the log output means. My log file contains the following output which I understand:

```
46834.386: [Full GC 46834.386: [CMS: 412190K->414324K(8388608K), 2.9557920 secs] 4319571K->414324K(16769088K), [CMS Perm : 96586K->96555K(2097152K)], 2.9561693 secs]
49394.883: [GC 49394.883: [ParNew: 8372352K->0K(8380480K), 0.0256383 secs] 8786676K->422169K(16769088K), 0.0258842 secs]
```

but it also contains the following output which I don't really understand:

```
 CMS: abort preclean due to time 2087298.141: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 

0.680/1.055 secs]
2087298.146: [GC[YG occupancy: 7515768 K (8380480 K)]2087298.146: [Rescan (parallel) , 5.0710721 secs]2087303.217: [weak refs processing, 0.0718252 secs] [1 CMS-remark: 3769931K(8388608K)] 11285700K(16769088K), 5.1432270 secs]
2087303.289: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2087305.311: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 2.022/2.022 secs]
2087305.311: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2087305.393: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.082/0.082 secs]
2087307.415: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 3769806K(8388608K)] 12129341K(16769088K), 4.3876237 secs]
2087311.803: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2087311.816: [GC 2087311.816: [ParNew: 8372352K->0K(8380480K), 0.2496844 secs] 12142158K->3865939K(16769088K), 0.2499456 secs]
2087318.573: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 6.508/6.770 secs]
2087318.573: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2087319.007: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.410/0.434 secs]
2087319.007: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
```

Currently I am using regular expressions to separate log output that has the format from the top. It segragates the output based on eden/tenured garbage collections. My question now is, what are these log output statements on the bottom? Are they eden or tenure garbage colletions?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: take a look here for more information about CMS http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/cms-6.html. Also there is a visual tool which allows to visualize GC impact http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html - maybe it can help you...

Comment: also this is very good article http://kramasundar.blogspot.com/2010/05/parallel-gc-vs-concurrent-gc.html and http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/10/java-cg-hotspots-cms-and-heap.html

Answer (score 2):

[ GCViewer] http://www.tagtraum.com/gcviewer.html is for you. You can download source code aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information on CMS GC log [here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/12/garbage-collection-in-hotspot-jvm.html). In shot they are specific non-stop-the-world phases of CMS algorithms.

Though I would advise you not to parse GC log, their format is clumsy unstable and some times they can get unparsable due to multithreaded logging.

Check JMX base alternative described [here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/04/using-hotspot-attach-api-for-fun-and.html).